# Find the vector given the dot product and cross product of a set of vectors.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, determinant, inner-products

This question comes from *Ted Shifrin's Multivariable Mathematics*. The question states:

> Given the nonzero vector $\textbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, $\textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{x} = b \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\textbf{a} \times \textbf{x} = \textbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, can you determine the vector $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$? If so give a geometric construction of $\textbf{x}$.

I'm trying to visualize what the vector $\textbf{x}$'s would look like in this scenario, but I think I'm getting confused by everything happening. So $\textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{x} = b$ is giving me the equation of a plane, in particular an affine plane from the one at the origin. As well $\textbf{a} \times \textbf{x} = \textbf{c}$ is giving me vector orthogonal to $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{x}$ respectively. The norm of this cross product also gives me the area of the parallelogram spanned by $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{x}$. Even with all these properties I'm still having trouble figuring out how to solve for $\textbf{x}$.

Would I be able to get some assistance? If I'm lucky maybe the man himself actually might pop in to provide guidance.

Comment: The title is just wrong, so better to use words and say something less misleading — something like "find the vector given dot product and cross product"? Your first conclusion is right, but your second one isn't. You want to draw conclusions about $\mathbf x$, given $\mathbf c$. Can you rephrase correctly?

Comment: Assuming there is a solution, are you able to describe geometrically what the set of all solutions $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\textbf{a} \times \textbf{x} = \textbf{c}$ looks like?

Comment: You've correctly described the set of solutions $\textbf{x}$ to $\textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{x} = b$. Can you also describe the set of solutions $\textbf{x}$ to $\textbf{a} \times \textbf{x} = \textbf{c}$? You've said something about $\textbf{c}$ in terms of $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{x}$, but we really want to say something about $\textbf{x}$ in terms of $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{c}$.

Comment: @CatalinZara Way too hard.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Changed the title....well essentially copied what you wrote and made it more verbose....

Comment: So, three of us have agreed that you should tell us what the solutions of $\mathbf a\times\mathbf x = \mathbf c$ look like. And, while you're at it, how are $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf c$ necessarily related?

Comment: @CatalinZara: So you've replaced geometric thinking with a formula that most students don't know and don't need. You going to derive it or just google and copy? I mean: I wrote a post on MSE years ago explaining how to think about it and derive it, but I disparage the use of formulas to replace thinking.

Comment: So @TedShifrin $\mathbf a \times\mathbf x = \mathbf c$ gives me a set of normal vectors, each one orthogonal to the plane spanned by $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf x$. Now $\mathbf x$ lies in the plane described by $\textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{x} = b$, But $\mathbf x$ could go in any direction in the plane $\textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{x} = b$....grrr.....I'm missing something.....

Comment: Geometrically: generically, ${\bf x}$ , ${\bf a}$, and ${\bf a} \times {\bf c}$ are three vectors orthogonal to ${\bf c}$. Hence, generically, ${\bf x}$ is a linear combination of ${\bf a}$  and ${\bf a} \times {\bf c}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**BIG HINT**: Note that the equation $\mathbf a\times\mathbf x = \mathbf c$ tells us that $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf c$ are orthogonal. Draw a picture of an example. Say $\mathbf c$ is a vector along the positive $\mathbf e_3$-axis. Then $\mathbf a$ must be a vector in the $xy$-plane. Draw it in a convenient location. Last, relative to it, where must $\mathbf x$ be located in order for the equation $\mathbf a\times\mathbf x = \mathbf c$ to hold? You mentioned the area of a parallelogram. Draw the possible locations (and there are infinitely many) of $\mathbf x$ to arrive at that.

Comment: Hi professor Shifrin, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996079/understanding-the-definition-of-exterior-derivative), please?

Comment: To take you away from the convo in the chat for a moment: Using your advice.In order for $\textbf{a} \times \textbf{x}= \textbf{c}$ to hold it means that $\textbf{x}$ could be any linear combination of vectors in the plane spanned by $\textbf{a, x}$, except for a scalar multiple of the vector $\textbf{a}$ itself. If I take the cross product of $\textbf{a} \times \textbf{c}$, I would get a vector that would have to be in the plane spanned by $\textbf{a, x}$. Even with the last comment Catalin Zara said above, I'm stuck trying to express things using only the objects given.

Comment: Oh, I had forgotten this was your post. Sorry. No, it can't at all be any vector in the plane. You can't refer to the plane spanned by $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf x$ when the latter is unknown. We're in the plane orthogonal to $\mathbf c$. That's the plane. Now you have to use the area criterion (plus right-hand rule). There's a *unique* vector in the plane orthogonal to $\mathbf a$ that works; now what else works?

Comment: I don't believe it has been an hour and I'm still struggling on this. So I'm going to write out what I'm thinking and hopefully you can nudge me along:  We're in the plane orthogonal to $\mathbf{c}$. This plane is spanned by the vector $\mathbf{a}$ and some other vector we are calling $\mathbf{x}$. Now the area of the parallelogram spanned by $\mathbf{a, x}$ is given by $||\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{x}||$. This is just a scalar number. Perhaps what I'm missing from here is being able to express the area of the parallelogram in an equivalent form. You also mention the plane orthogonal (cont'd)

Comment: to $\mathbf{a}$. The way to get a plane orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$ is by taking the cross product of $\mathbf{a}$ with some other vector. The only other vector I have is $\mathbf{c}$. Doing that I would get an expression of $\mathbf{a} \times (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{x})$. I know there are "formulas" to manipulate this, but in using your text I "don't know" these formulas. So I cannot use them to manipulate things, plus I don't want to. I want to get the geometric understanding of what's happening.

Comment: No, you keep making the same basic error. $\mathbf x$ is an unknown, so you don't get to say it's one of the basis vectors of the plane. How does area work for a parallelogram in a plane? Did you answer my (implicit) question to find the unique vector in the plane orthogonal to $\mathbf a$ that works? How does that give you the rest of the vectors?

Comment: Finding the area of a parallelogram revolves around taking the product of the "length" and "height". So if I let $\mathbf{a}$ be the length vector, then to find the "height" vector I would have to find $\mathbf{x}^{\perp} = \mathbf{x} - \frac{\mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{a}}{||\mathbf{a}||}\mathbf{a}$. Then the area of the parallelogram would be $||\mathbf{x}^{\perp}|| \cdot ||\mathbf{a}||$ (regular multiplication)  thinking of it that $\mathbf{x}^{\perp}$ would be what is orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$. How that gives me the rest?...working on that at the moment. Assuming my reasoning above is right

Comment: typo, should be $||\mathbf{a}||^{2}$ in the denominator of the expression of $\mathbf{x}^{\perp}$

Comment: You're making this too hard, because you didn’t start with my question. We start with a rectangle with the right area. Keeping the height the same keeps the area the same. This gives a line parallel to $\mathbf a$.

Comment: Which of your questions in particular are you talking about?.....I also just did a bunch of work and arrived at a point where I have the norm of $\mathbf{x}$ in terms of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{c}$. Would it be easier to write out here or in the chat?

Comment: I kept asking you here to find the solution orthogonal to $\mathbf a$.

Comment: Ok......So $\mathbf{c}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{c}$ is also orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$. I also have the $\mathbf{x}^{\perp}$ that I worked out that would be orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: We're trying to solve for all the $\mathbf x$. Reread all my comments again.

Comment: I'll reread them all and come up with a solution and write out the key parts here. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: For future reference, if you want to use MSE or MSE chat as a constructive learning tool, you have to pay attention to what we say — every detail. Follow-up questions are fine, but you need to demonstrate that you've read and tried what we suggest.

Comment: 1) Where must $\mathbf{x}$ be in order for $\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{c}$ to hold?:   Using the idea of $\mathbf{c}$ being the $\mathbf{e_{3}}$-axis. This means that $\mathbf{x}$ is also in the $xy$ - plane along with $\mathbf{a}$.

2) Area of the parallelogram is given by $||\mathbf{c}|| = ||\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{x}||$. But it is also given by $||\mathbf{x}^{\perp}|| \cdot ||\mathbf{a}||$ (regular multiplication). You mentioned keeping the height the same keeps the area the same. So I have to somehow express $\mathbf{x}^{\perp}$ as a constant.

Comment: I'm convinced $\mathbf{x}^{\perp}$ is at the centre of the correct argument, but I have not arrived at expressing the quantities correctly.

Comment: Hint: Let $u=-a\times(a\times x)+a(a\cdot x)$ then compute $a\times u$ and $a\cdot u$.

Comment: I already said this: Start with the rectangle with base $\mathbf a$ and height the vector $\mathbf x_0$ perpendicular to it with length $\|\mathbf c\|/\|\mathbf a\|$ (you have to choose the correct one to get the right-hand rule to work). This vector is one $\mathbf x$ that works. Now, to keep the same vector $\mathbf x^\perp$, we take $\mathbf x$ any vector on the line through $\mathbf x_0$ parallel to $\mathbf a$. These are all the solutions $\mathbf x$.