# How to determine a vector in $\mathbb R^3$ from its dot and cross products with a given vector

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vectors, cross-product

Suppose we have a vector $a$ in $\mathbb R^3$ and an unknown vector $v$, but we know $a \cdot v$ and $a \times v$. Can we find $v$? How?

Sources: Based on Shifrin's *Multivariable Mathematics* and [MIT OCW 18.013A](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter05/section06.html).

My solution is below, to which I request verification and suggestions.  *Note: Other solutions exist, such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3994814/find-the-vector-given-the-dot-product-and-cross-product-of-a-set-of-vectors); this question is to verify and critique my solution.*

---

Let $$a,v,c \in \mathbb R^3 \\ d \in \mathbb R \\ a \cdot v = d \\ a \times v = c.$$  Given $a,c,d$, find $v$.

Any $v$ can be decomposed into $v = v_{\parallel} + v_{\perp}$, where $v_{\parallel} \parallel a, v_{\perp} \perp a$.  Therefore

$$\begin{align}
v_{\parallel} &= \frac d {a \cdot a} \, a \\
\|v_{\perp}\| &= \frac {\|c\|}{\|a\|}\\
\end{align}$$
since parallelogram area $\|c\|$ is base $\|a\|$ times height $\|v_{\perp}\|$.

Since $c$ is perpindicular to both $a$ and $v$, we have $$\begin{align}
c \cdot v &= 0 \\
c \cdot (v_{\parallel} + v_{\perp}) &= 0 \\
c \cdot v_{\perp} &= 0
\end{align}$$ and $v_{\perp}$ is $\perp$ to both $a$ and $c$ and therefore parallel to $a \times c$:

$$\widehat{v_{\perp}} = \pm \frac {c \times a}{\|c \times a\|}.$$

In fact, $\widehat{v_{\perp}} = \frac {c \times a}{\|c \times a\|}$.  To see this, consider the case where $a = i$ and $v$ is in the first or second quadrant.  Then $\hat c = k$ and $\widehat{v_{\perp}} = j = \frac {c \times a} {\| c \times a\|}$.  Since cross product is invariant under rotation, any $a, c$ and $v$ are equivalent to this.

This gives us $$v = \frac d {a \cdot a} \, a + \frac {\|c\|}{\|a\| \|c \times a\|} \, c \times a.$$

**Update:** which, as Ted Shifrin and ghasheem point out, simplifies to

$$\begin{align}v &= \frac d {a \cdot a} \, a + \frac {c \times a}{\|a\|^2}\\
v &= \frac {da + c \times a} {a \cdot a}.\end{align}$$

Comment: *Notation:* `\|v\|` gives better spaced norm bars than `||v||`: compare $\|v\|$ vs. $||v||$.

Comment: So what are you solving? What's the question?

Comment: Are you sure that $a\times v=c$? Proof? By the way, as the author I’ll tell you that my interest was in a geometric solution, rather than an algebraic one, but of course a valid proof is a valid proof. I don’t yet see why yours is that.

Comment: I do not get the right answer at all when I compute $a \times c$. The orientation is wrong and the scalar multiple is not correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin Re the scalar multiple: I divided by the length to eliminate the scalar multiple, so I argue the proof is still correct.  I changed the LaTeX to `\widehat` to make this more noticeable.  Re orientation: This was indeed my error, because I mistakenly assumed i×k=j when in truth i×k=−j. I fixed this and also clarified the argument.  Can you take a look?

Comment: Yes, this is fine. Note (as I didn’t stop to check earlier) that $\|c\times a\|= \|a\|\|c\|$, so your coefficient simplifies to $\|a\|^2$.

Comment: I mean $1/\|a\|^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $ a \times v = c$, then $c$ must be orthogonal to $a$, otherwise there is no solution.  Vector $v$ is orthogonal to $c$, so it lies in the plane spanned by $ a $ and $ a \times c $

$ v = \alpha a + \beta (a \times c) $

Substituting $v$ into $ a \times v = c $ gives

$ \beta ( a \times (a \times c) ) = c $

Now,

$ a \times (a \times c) = a ( a \cdot c) - c (a \cdot a ) $

The first term is zero because $c$ is orthogonal to $a$.  Therefore

$ \beta = - \dfrac{1}{ (a \cdot a ) } $

while $\alpha$ is determined from the dot product with $a$

$ v \cdot a = \alpha (a \cdot a) = d $

so $ \alpha = \dfrac{d}{a \cdot a } $

Therefore,

$ v = \dfrac{1}{a \cdot a } ( d a - (a \times c) ) $

Comment: Elegant and sharp! How did you think of taking this approach?

Comment: Actually I learned it in school several years ago.